# Regular expression to match comma or newline but not both

Tags: python, regex, csv

I've got a problem with the following python script which extracts some options from text in an internal company web app text area.

```
import re

text = 'option one\noption two, option three, option four'
correct = 'option one, option two, option three, option four'

pattern = re.compile('(\s*[,]\s*)')
fixed = pattern.sub(', ', text)

print fixed
option one
option two, option three, option four

print fixed.split(', ')
['option one\noption two', 'option three', 'option four']
```

This obviously fails to split up 'option one\noption two' into 'option one', 'option two'

So the input could end up as

```
option one
option two, option three, option four
```

which would need to be converted to

```
option one, option two, option three, option four
```

it works fine if its a comma

or

a comma followed by a newline

but not if its just a newline by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend your character class from `[,]` to `[,\n]`, maybe? Also, why don't you split on the regex directly, rather than search-and-replacing first and then splitting? This function: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html?highlight=re.split#re.split could come handy for this.

Comment: `re.split` is indeed the answer.

Comment: I never even noticed that slightly peculiar splitting method! But I'm not a pythonite anyway... :)

Comment: Nice one, '(\s*[,\n]\s*)' worked perfectly, thanks tdammers :-)

Comment: I've just had a look at re.split which I'd also never seen before. Its clearly more sensible than my attempt. I've tried re.split('(\s*[,\n]\s*)', text) and its returning all the commas as array items as well e.g. ['option one', ', ', 'option two', ', ', 'option three', ', ', 'option four']. Any idea why thats happening?

Comment: That's because you're using a capturing group. Ditch the parentheses, and it should work - that is, `'\s*[,\n]\s*'` instead of `'(\s*[,\n]\s*)'`

Comment: I just found out the original works without the parens as well :-)

Answer (score 3):

Can you just try

```
(\s*(,|\n)\s*)
```

?

Or probably even better

```
(\s*[,\n]\s*)
```

...I always forget you can put `\n` in a character class...

Comment: ah, sorry, I didn't notice you had given the correct answer first, whats the 'done thing' when that happens?, I've no idea since this is my first question...

Comment: @nih that's not a problem. Although I would say that tdammers has given you a more complete answer as they have suggested you simply split on the match. If there's nothing in it then I usually give it to whoever's got the least rep :D

Answer (score 2):

I got there without a regex:

```
print [x.strip() for x in text.replace('\n', ', ').split(', ')]
```

Result:

```
['option one', 'option two', 'option three', 'option four']
```

I'm not claiming this to be a good answer for your usage case. If you need to add extra delimiters it means adding an extra `.replace()` for each.